# How to instruct SQLAlchemy ORM to execute multiple queries in parallel when loading relationships?

Tags: python, mysql, orm, parallel-processing, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy's ORM. I have a model that has multiple many-to-many relationships:

```
User
User <--MxN--> Organization
User <--MxN--> School
User <--MxN--> Credentials
```

I am implementing these using [association tables](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many), so there are also User_to_Organization, User_to_School and User_to_Credentials tables that I don't directly use.

Now, when I attempt to load a single User (using its PK identifier) and its relationships (and related models) using joined eager loading, I get horrible performance (15+ seconds). I assume this is due to [this issue](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#what-kind-of-loading-to-use):

> When multiple levels of depth are used with joined or subquery loading, loading collections-within- collections will multiply the total number of rows fetched in a cartesian fashion. Both forms of eager loading always join from the original parent class.

If I introduce another level or two to the hierarchy:

```
Organization <--1xN--> Project
School <--1xN--> Course
Project <--MxN--> Credentials
Course <--MxN--> Credentials
```

The query takes 50+ seconds to complete, even though the total amount of records in each table is fairly small.

Using lazy loading, I am required to manually load each relationship, and there are multiple round trips to the server.

e.g.
Operations, executed serially as queries:

- Get user
- Get user's Organizations
- Get user's Schools
- Get user's credentials
- For each Organization, get its Projects
- For each School, get its Courses
- For each Project, get its Credentials
- For each Course, get its Credentials

Still, it all finishes in less than 200ms.

I was wondering if there is anyway to indeed use lazy loading, but perform the relationship loading queries in parallel. For example, using the `concurrent` module, `asyncio` or by using `gevent`.

e.g.
Step 1 (in parallel):

- Get user
- Get user's Organizations
- Get user's Schools
- Get user's credentials

Step 2 (in parallel):

- For each Organization, get its Projects
- For each School, get its Courses

Step 3 (in parallel):

- For each Project, get its Credentials
- For each Course, get its Credentials

Actually, at this point, making a subquery type load can also work, that is, return Organization and OrganizationID/Project/Credentials in two separate queries:

e.g.
Step 1 (in parallel):

- Get user
- Get user's Organizations
- Get user's Schools
- Get user's credentials

Step 2 (in parallel):

- Get Organizations
- Get Schools
- Get the Organizations' Projects, join with Credentials
- Get the Schools' Courses, join with Credentials

Comment: Let's see the SQL for your 15-second query; maybe we can work from there.

Comment: you can have a look at scoped sessions for a concurrent approach: [sqlalchemy: scoped session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html?highlight=scoped%20session)

Comment: Scoped sessions will not give you concurency - unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you're going to want to do is check to see what queries are actually being executed on the db. I wouldn't assume that SQLAlchemy is doing what you expect unless you're very familiar with it. You can use `echo=True` on your engine configuration or look at some db logs (not sure how to do that with mysql).

You've mentioned that you're using different loading strategies so I guess you've read through the docs on that (
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html). For what you're doing, I'd probably recommend subquery load, but it totally depends on the number of rows / columns you're dealing with. In my experience it's a good general starting point though.

One thing to note, you might need to something like:

`db.query(Thing).options(subqueryload('A').subqueryload('B')).filter(Thing.id==x).first()`

With `filter.first` rather that `get`, as the latter case won't re-execute queries according to your loading strategy if the primary object is already in the identity map.

Finally, I don't know your data - but those numbers sound pretty abysmal for anything short of a huge data set. Check that you have the correct indexes specified on all your tables.

You may have already been through all of this, but based on the information you've provided, it sounds like you need to do more work to narrow down your issue. Is it the db schema, or is it the queries SQLA is executing?

Either way, I'd say, "no" to running multiple queries on different connections. Any attempt to do that could result in inconsistent data coming back to your app, and if you think you've got issues now..... :-)

Comment: I'll definitely go deeper soon, and indeed I'll post an update here (and create a new bounty).

Comment: The last point of your comment is unclear to me, though - why is it "more" inconsistent as opposed to making several sequential queries? many more things can change in that span of time. True, if you make a single query and get everything in "one go" then there are no consistency issues for the query, but then again - you get into the cartesian multiplication result size explosion valley :)

Comment: Because the database manages the transaction for you so that the data is consistent within your transaction. If you use multiple connections (to get concurrency) you will have multiple transactions and each of them will have a view of the data at different moments in time. Forget about that idea - it's not a done thing.

Comment: Whatever your issue is (my guess would be that sqla is doing eager loading and is running loads of tiny queries), multiple transactions will just be hell on earth (and probably won't make anything faster)

Comment: *isn't eager loading

Comment: Why would parallel READ transactions from separate tables not respect the boundaries of a transaction, though? I use READ COMMITTED regardless.

Comment: You won't get concurrency if you're using the same connection / transaction. Either way, you're looking in the wrong place to solve your issue. I expect to be able to retrieve a lot of data from any database in (well) under a second - the fact you're not getting anywhere near that is the core issue. Really, it should have taken less time to diagnose that than has been spent discussing it. I'm interested to hear the cause, but there's nothing more I can do from here other than to say _don't waste time on the parallel thing_

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has no parallelism in a single connection.  For the ORM to do such would require multiple connections to MySQL.  Generally, the overhead of trying to do such is "not worth it".

To get a `user`, his `Organizations`, `Schools`, etc, can all be done (in mysql) via a single query:

```
SELECT user, organization, ...
    FROM Users
    JOIN Organizations ON ...
    etc.
```

This is significantly more efficient than

```
SELECT user FROM ...;
SELECT organization ... WHERE user = ...;
etc.
```

(This is not "parallelism".)

Or maybe your "steps" are not quite 'right'?...

```
SELECT user, organization, project
    FROM Users
    JOIN Organizations ...
    JOIN Projects ...
```

That gets, in a single step, all users, together with all their organizations and projects.

But is a "user" associated with a "project"?  If not, then this is the wrong approach.

If the ORM is not providing a mechanism to generate queries like those, than it is "getting in the way".

Comment: True, no parallelism in a single connection. I am talking about multiple connections - they're just lying there, inactive. Why not use them? Why is it "not worth it" if you save the largest interval in the process, the network boundary, return-time trip interval?

Comment: As I said above, the issue with the joins you are talking about is that we get to cartesian multiplications, and the amount of data spikes - and it includes tons of repetition. The user data can be repeated each time, per row. Sure, with lower cardinality this isn't a issue. It does get problematic fast, and especially so if we're using association tables, with state. Yes, a User is associated with a Project - he took part in a Project. He then got the relevant certification/"Credentials". Your last part does make sense - I thought I might move to non-ORM usage for some code sections. Shame..

Comment: Justin Swanhart has a package of tools that turn your SQL into parallel SQL.